# Linux and unicode

Tags: linux, scala, vim, intellij-idea, character-encoding

I know (or I think I know) about char encoding unicode as much as is in this article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html .

[image: Linux ❤ Unicode]

I saved a japanese character in a file, and opening it in multiple ways gives me multiple results.

Counterclockwise (roughly)

1. 'cat' inside yakuake shows me the right results.
2. vim inside yakuake doesn't show it right!
3. gvim opened from yakuake shows it wrong too. (Bigger gvim in center
   of screen)
4. gvim opened from Alt-F2 shows it right, bottom gvim.
5. Intellij opening it directly shows it right.  (not in image)
6. Reading using scala in Intellij shows it wrong.    `scala.io.Source.fromFile( , "UTF-8" ).mkString`

Could someone tell me please what's up here? Specially the vim inconsistency? I can bear Linux(X) and Intellij behaving arbitrarily, but vim doing that tells me that it's my understanding that's faulty.

EDIT: To answer @user3666209's question, all the vim/gvim's have 'empty' file encoding.

Comment: What is the output of the vim command `:set fileencoding?`?

Comment: all the vim/gvim's have 'empty' file encoding. Edited question to show this fact. When I do :set fileencoding=UTF8, or UTF-8, I don't see any change..

Comment: Do you know which encoding your terminal is using? Or which encoding was used to save the file? I think the encoding of the terminal is the same as the file encoding, according to the correct result output by cat.

Comment: try `:e ++enc=utf8` in vim, AFTER opening the file.

Comment: try `file -bi <your file name>` to check the encoding and convert it with `iconv` if necessary. Your terminal might need to have additional fonts installed to display these chars.

Comment: `:set fileencoding=XXX` is used to save the file in the specified encoding, not to reopen it in the encoding. If you want to reopen it in the encoding, `:edit ++encoding=XXX` shall be used instead.

Comment: I won't suggest using `file` to detect the file encoding, because in my personally experience it won't get the correct result. For example, all my big5 documents are reported by `file` as iso-8859-1 files.

Comment: @user3666209
I saved the file by opening Alt-F2 -> gvim, Ctrl-Shift-U and then entering the unicode (which I don't remember!).
The terminal encoding is UTF-8. Not sure what the file was saved as, but <pre>file </pre> on the file gives: /tmp/japanis: UTF-8 Unicode text

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov
<code> file -bi <fn> </code> gives:
text/plain; charset=utf-8


Terminal shows the correct output anyway..

Comment: @user3666209
:e ++enc=utf8 gives conversion error in vim after opening the file and the charachter changes to a ?

Comment: Are you asking a unicode question without showing us your system's settings?

Comment: [This is what I get on an almost stock Ubuntu VM](http://i.imgur.com/QRaP1VI.png). Tell us more about your system's settings, fonts, whatever that can help us help you.

Comment: Honestly, I feel like a noob. I don't know which settings you're talking about.  
/etc/*release  

DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint  
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16  
DISTRIB_CODENAME=petra  
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 16 Petra"  
NAME="Ubuntu"  
VERSION="13.10, Saucy Salamander"  
ID=ubuntu  
ID_LIKE=debian  
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 13.10"  
VERSION_ID="13.10"  
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"  
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"  
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"  

I know know too lttl to make such stmts, but don't look like font's issue. IntelliJ can/can't show. Gvim can/can't show

Comment: Sorry last comment was too long. In any case, please let me know which other settings should I tell you about. 
It's a Linux 16 Mint. And I'm using xfce. Let me post the output of set, one sec

Comment: settings: http://pastebin.com/aWYUWRqe

Comment: @romainl Here's the font list: http://pastebin.com/XyfT85ph

Comment: You said ":e ++enc=utf8 gives conversion error in vim" which could mean the file isn't actually saved as utf-8. I'm not sure, it may also mean that Vim is running with the wrong internal encoding. What does "`:set encoding?`" return?

Comment: @Ben: :set encoding on vim from terminal and gvim from terminal is latin-1. 
Changing encoding on vim still didn't show the file right, changing encoding on gvim from terminal showed it right.

Comment: @Ben Actually, even vim from terminal shows it right. Just now I was using VNC and vnc sessions probably start with some weird encoding, so I changed it to utf-8 and even terminal vim works fine. So I guess terminal encoding and vi encoding are important. Looks like this is solved. Is it..?
Also, anyone knows what might be up with IntelliJ?

Comment: And looks like the IntelliJ issue was file.encoding system property. 
I did : export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' 
and all was well there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone who answered!

Reasons of vim inconsistency, wrong 'encoding' for vims open from terminal and separately. Solved by :set encoding=utf8 inside vim.

Also set my terminal's encoding to utf8 otherwise cat would give wrong results.

For java, use  `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'`